# How to follow group by time

Tags: r, data.table, lag

I have a data frame as below:

```
user   time
____   ____
 1      2017-09-01 00:01:01
 1      2017-09-01 00:01:20
 1      2017-09-01 00:03:01
 1      2017-09-01 00:10:01
 1      2017-09-01 00:11:01
 2      2017-09-01 00:01:03
 2      2017-09-01 00:01:08
 2      2017-09-01 00:03:01
```

From this data frame I want to create the follow group for each user like below:

```
user           time                      follow_group
____   ____________________             _____________                            
 1      2017-09-01 00:01:01                 1
 1      2017-09-01 00:01:20                 1  
 1      2017-09-01 00:03:01                 1 
 1      2017-09-01 00:10:01                 2
 1      2017-09-01 00:11:01                 2
 2      2017-09-01 00:01:03                 1
 2      2017-09-01 00:01:08                 1
 2      2017-09-01 00:03:01                 1
```

The follow group for each user changes when the time difference is greater than 5 minutes.

I tried by taking the lag and subtracting:

```
data[, previous_request_time:=c(NA, time[-.N]), by=user]
```

But that didn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do a `difftime` operation and check if the difference is greater than 5 mins. Then a cumulative sum will give your group counter:

```
dat[,
  follow_group := cumsum(difftime(time, shift(time, fill=-Inf), units="mins") > 5),
  by=user
]

#   user                time follow_group
#1:    1 2017-09-01 00:01:01            1
#2:    1 2017-09-01 00:01:20            1
#3:    1 2017-09-01 00:03:01            1
#4:    1 2017-09-01 00:10:01            2
#5:    1 2017-09-01 00:11:01            2
#6:    2 2017-09-01 00:01:03            1
#7:    2 2017-09-01 00:01:08            1
#8:    2 2017-09-01 00:03:01            1
```

You could similarly use just `diff` if you didn't want to be too explicit about the units:

```
dat[, flwgrp := cumsum(c(Inf, diff(time)) > 5*60), by=user]
```